# How to delete the OneDrive reparse point?

Tags: windows, symbolic-link, onedrive, reparse-points

I replaced the HDD from my machine by an SSD, and I'm trying to use the old HDD for other purposes, without reformatting it. My new SSD is booting as `C:\` and the old HDD (which used to be `C:\`) is now under `E:\`. The first thing is to get rid of all reparse points that point to `C:\`. For that, I'm using `fsutil reparsepoint delete` on every reparse point under `E:\` that points to `C:\`.

Everything was working magically, until I hit `E:\Users\myname\OneDrive`. It turns out that it's a special reparse point, because although it *does* show up under `dir /al`, it's not `<JUNCTION>` neither `<SYMLINK>`. It's listed as `<DIR>` only:

```
E:\Users\myname> dir /al
 Volume in drive E is OS
 Volume Serial Number is 72E7-C9BC

 Directory of F:\Users\myname

05/26/2022  02:20 PM    <DIR>          OneDrive
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               1 Dir(s)  119,188,217,856 bytes free
```

I can confirm that it's a reparse point using `fsutil reparsepoint query`:

```
E:\Users\myname> fsutil reparsepoint query "OneDrive"
Reparse Tag Value : <redacted>

Reparse Data Length: 0x6c
Reparse Data:
0000:  <redacted>
0010:  <redacted>
0020:  <redacted>
0030:  <redacted>
0040:  <redacted>
0050:  <redacted>
0060:  <redacted>

E:\Users\myname> rem Running again for a directory that is not a reparse point:

E:\Users\myname> fsutil reparsepoint query "Contacts"
Error:  The file or directory is not a reparse point.
```

Now if I try to delete that reparse point, I get this error:

```
E:\Users\myname> fsutil reparsepoint delete "OneDrive"
Error:  Access to the cloud file is denied.
```

I've seen other posts saying to simply delete the `OneDrive` directory with `rd /s` or `Remove-Item`, however I do have files on the cloud `OneDrive`, and I'm afraid that if I delete from my HDD, I would delete my files.

I have attempted to quit OneDrive and pause sync, but that does not get rid of error `Access to the cloud file is denied`.

Is there a way to force-delete the reparse point to OneDrive on `E:\` without sorting to a backup of my OneDrive files? Maybe editing directory permissions or changing some configuration such as a registry setting?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:
`chkdsk <volume> /R /F`

Ref:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/troubleshoot/sync/delete-onedrive-synced-file-error